# href sms not working on iphone (website app or webview app)

Tags: html, ios, iphone

I've an app of my website. It's basically webview app. there is a button for opening the messaging app with number. it open when I try to click that button using browser. but not working on app. I've found many question on stackoverflow and it seems they are very old question. also **mailto:**
is working just fine.

```
<a href="sms://+15552345678;?&body=Hello%20World">Send Message</a>
```

I'm using above html tag. It's just work on every mobile and devices. but it's not working on the webview app. any idea to make it workable.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @bingeScripter not yet..